# How to create sub-headers in org-mode (emacs)?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Hello I was wondering how to create sub-headers in an org document. I have tried this:

```
* header 
  * sub-header
    Some text
```

The `*` works for the header part but will create bullets instead of sub-headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for these kind of questions the org-manual is the best place to check: https://orgmode.org/org.html#Headlines

> Headlines define the structure of an outline tree. The headlines in Org start with one or more stars, on the left margin3. For example:

```
* Top level headline
** Second level
*** Third level
    some text
*** Third level
    more text
* Another top level headline
```

Hope, this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to the answer by @sanenr9, you can also enable a "clean view" that hides all but the last star in a heading if you prefer (see [A Cleaner Outline View](https://orgmode.org/manual/Clean-View.html#Clean-View)): the asterisks are still there in the buffer but they are hidden using an overlay.

Another useful hint is to examine the "Org" entry in the menu: there are many useful commands there (generally with a keyboard shortcut as well). E.g. you can add a new heading at the same level as the previous heading by clicking on the "New Heading" entry in the "Org" menu and you can then make it into a subheading by clicking on
"Org/Edit Structure/Demote heading" menu item (or you can use the indicated keyboard shortcut `M-<right>` which is done by holding down the Meta key and pressing the right arrow key.)